# Chef registry_key resource give unexpected result in rspec test

Tags: rspec, chef-infra

I'm getting a weird result from a chefspec test of a resource in an LWRP.  The resource look like this:

```
registry_key "disable #{connection_mode} #{protocol}" do
  key "#{protocols_key}\\#{protocol}\\#{connection_mode}"
  values [{ name: 'Enabled', type: :dword, data: 0 }]
  recursive true
  action :create
end
```

And the test for this resource is giving me the following result:

```
Failure/Error:
 expect(chef_run).to create_registry_key("disable #{connection_mode} #{protocol}")
   .with(key: "#{protocols_registry_key}\\#{protocol}\\#{connection_mode}",
         values: [{ name: 'Enabled', type: :dword, data: 0 }],
         recursive: true)

  expected "registry_key[disable Client protocol_1]" to have parameters:

   values [{:name=>"Enabled", :type=>:dword, :data=>0}], was [{:name=>"Enabled", :type=>:dword, :data=>"5feceb66ffc86f38d952786c6d696c79c2dbc239dd4e91b46729d73a27fb57e9"}]
```

Why would the resource be generating that weird string instead of the value 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the SHA256 of `"0"`. See also https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/resource/registry_key.rb#L135-L136

If you change the test to `.with(key: ..., unscrubbed_values: ..., recursive: true)` you'll probably see the expected stuffs.